# How to add required if validation rule if a file has been uploaded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and here is my validation request form:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'art_audio_file' => ['nullable', 'file', 'mimes:audio/mpeg,mpga,mp3,wav,aac'],
            'art_audio_file_title' => ['required_if: IF USER HAS UPLOADED FILE']
        ];
    }
```

I wonder, how can I make `art_audio_file_title` required if `art_audio_file` is not empty.

So how can I do that?

Comment: Hasn't this been asked already today?

Comment: @brombeer Yes but no one answered!

Answer (score 0):

You can add your logic like below:

```
return [
      'art_audio_file' => ['nullable', 'file', 'mimes:audio/mpeg,mpga,mp3,wav,aac'],
      'art_audio_file_title' => [
          Rule::requiredIf(function() {
              return !empty($this->request->get('art_audio_file'));
          })
      ]
    ];
```

or in your case simply:

`'art_audio_file_title'=>'required_with:art_audio_file'`

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule::requiredIf()

Comment: And the second one also not working

Comment: You must use it before call.
`use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;`

Comment: I have included it now, I tried choosing a file to upload, I left the `art_audio_file_title`  empty to check if it shows the required message, but it adds the data to the DB without showing require message!

Comment: Both required_with helper function and requiredIf Rule is available in your laravel version, you can see this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

Comment: Its weird, please add your request parameters bag sample and your HTML snippet to the question.